# Switchable graphics Intel + AMD Venus Pro

Tags: graphics, manjaro, radeon, amd-graphics, bumblebee

I'm using Manjaro Linux on my laptop with switchable graphic cards:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X] (rev ff)
```

Here's a screenshot of the drivers section of Manjaro Settings Manager:

[image: Manjaro Settings Manager]

The above shows that bumblebee's drivers are installed, but the daemon fails:

```
[luke@manjaro ~]$ sudo systemctl status bumblebeed
● bumblebeed.service - Bumblebee C Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since pią 2015-09-18 16:22:55 CEST; 29s ago
  Process: 1192 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bumblebeed (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1192 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

wrz 18 16:22:55 manjaro systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Unit entered failed state.
wrz 18 16:22:55 manjaro systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

During my trial-and-error I also tried to install `video-catalyst` driver (in window shown above). It ended miserably - after the initial startup the screen was full white. I switched to another TTY and deleted video-catalyst using `mhwd`.

My goal is to be able to play games on Steam. What can you recommend?

Comment: Bumblebee is for NVIDIA cards. It does not support ATI Radeon cards.

Comment: I've heard that. But how to explain that driver named "video-hybrid-intel-ati-bumblebee"?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered/tried primus?

```
https://github.com/amonakov/primus
```

I'm not too familiar with the whole thing, but it seems like it has replaced `bumblebee` in most use cases.

Looks like it is known to compile on `arch` so you should be able to get it functioning on `manjaro`